# predict function throws an error : "Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: t is not a function"

Tags: angular, tensorflow.js

I have trained a model in google teachable machine and used the model to predict emotions of human face. I'm using '@teachablemachine/image' npm package in angular to load and predict. The model loads but while predict it throws an error:

```
core.js:6486 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: t is not a function
TypeError: t is not a function
    at engine.ts:583
    at engine.ts:423
    at t.scopedRun (engine.ts:434)
    at t.tidy (engine.ts:421)
    at c (engine.ts:583)
    at engine.ts:596
    at t.scopedRun (engine.ts:434)
    at t.runKernelFunc (engine.ts:593)
    at t.runKernel (engine.ts:492)
    at fromPixels_ (browser.js:109)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1213)
    at zone.js:1120
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:6)
    at _throw (asyncToGenerator.js:29)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:372)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:28680)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:371)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:134)
    at zone.js:1276
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406)
```

I think the error is in the line: `const prediction = await this.model.predict(this.webcam.canvas);`

the component.ts file looks like:

```
..
import * as tmImage from '@teachablemachine/image';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

..
..

export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild('video') video: ElementRef;
  
  model:any;
  webcam: any;
  labelContainer: any;
  maxPredictions: any; 
predictions: Prediction[];

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }


  async init() {

    const modelURL = "../assets/tm-my-image-model/model.json";
    const metadataURL = "../assets/tm-my-image-model/metadata.json";

    // load the model and metadata
   
    this.model = await tmImage.load(modelURL, metadataURL);
    this.maxPredictions = this.model.getTotalClasses();

    // Convenience function to setup a webcam
    const flip = true; // whether to flip the webcam
    this.webcam = new tmImage.Webcam(200, 200, flip); // width, height, flip
    await this.webcam.setup(); // request access to the webcam
    await this.webcam.play();
    await this.webcam.renderCameraToCanvas();

    setInterval(async () => {
      await this.webcam.renderCameraToCanvas();
      const prediction = await this.model.predict(this.webcam.canvas);
      }, 1);
    
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.video.nativeElement, this.webcam.canvas)
    
}
  
}
```

How to predict without any error?

Comment: first, `tfjs` must be imported before `@teachablemachine`.
best guess is the fact that `@teachablemachine` is pretty much obsolete (and based on `tfjs` 1.3.1. compatibility with current tfjs (currently at 3.11.0) is sketchy at best

Comment: I did, but it did not work.